# mapbox gl calculate inside expression for circle-radius

Tags: expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'd like to do a calculation inside an expression. Is this possbile?
The code I have for now doesn't work. This example works fine:

```
'circle-radius': {
    'base': 1.5,
        'stops': [
            [0, 0],
            [20, 180]
        ]
}
```

But when I do a calculation inside, it doesnt work:

```
'circle-radius': {
    'base': 1.5,
    'stops': [
        [0, 0],
        [20, ['*', 2, 90]]
    ]
},
```

And what I'm really trying to do in the end is `adding another variable` from my data.

```
'circle-radius': {
    'base': 1.5,
    'stops': [
        [0, 0],
        [20, ['*', 2, ["get", "amount"]]]
    ]
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two different Mapbox-GL syntaxes together: the older "stops" method, and the newer expression syntax. Since you want to do a calculation, you need to entirely use the new [expression syntax](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions).

Something like this:

```
{
    "circle-radius": [
        "interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"],
        0, 0,
        20, ['*', 2, ['get', 'amount']]]
    ]
}
```